# Redirect Json error when no json is being parsed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

I am trying to redirect from a controller action to another controller action.
Even though the debugger steps inside the second Controller  Action and appears to render it ,and even in the Browser -response section the page appears rendered and its status is `200 ok` i get:

```
Error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

And the page does not change.
The code:

**LocationController**

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Attach")]
        public IActionResult Attach([FromBody]List<Location> locations)
        {
                Story targetStory=TempData.Get<Story>("tstory");
                if(targetStory!=null && locations!=null)
                {
                    var slocs=this.context.StoryLocations.Where(sloc=>sloc.StoryId==targetStory.Id);
                    this.context.RemoveRange(slocs);
                    this.context.SaveChanges();
                    foreach(Location loc in locations)
                    {
                        this.context.StoryLocations.Add(new StoryLocation{LocationId=loc.Id,StoryId=targetStory.Id});
                    }
                    this.context.SaveChanges();
                }

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Story");
        }
```

**Story Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public string Test()
        {
            return test;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public  IActionResult Index()
        {
            TempData.Clear();
            List<Story>Stories=this.context.Stories.ToList();
            return View(this.context.Stories);

        }
```

I have tried to redirect to different actions from the second controller and the request is made and it is ok (status 200 green) but it wont change the view even though the chrome-response from "Story/Index" is ok.